# Are issues related to DevOps literature and educational materials on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I reviewed the answers in the Help Center and didn’t notice any restrictions on literature, technical documentation, training materials or resources for training and professional growth in this area.
Are this questions on-topic?

Comment: That's quite hard to answer, do you have an exemple of such a question ?

Comment: In example, [on ru.StackOverflow site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/262779) questions connected with books, and technical documentation is on-topic

Comment: Community questions like this are discouraged on the whole network now, they fade quite quickly and become stale with no one maintaining the links. So we're more on the side of wide topic, but focused question not needing a list of external link as answer. See https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/why-are-people-restricting-broad-questions-on-culture-and-process?rq=1 for rationale behind this

Comment: But books that have ISBN don't fade.

Comment: Well, they do each time what they describe become outdated, and for well known literature google is better than a list here, my 2 cts.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what we are talking about here. Is it about asking for a _list_ of resources_ ("What are the best books about DevOps?"), or about asking questions _related to_ some educational material ("I read in the XYZ book p123 that ... but I don't understand why"). The former will probably fade quickly. But the second, if properly written, is as valid as any other question. Or isn't it?